# iphone jquery-mobile download image

Tags: iphone, image, jquery-mobile, download

I have mobile site on jquery-mobile, which display gallery. There is button, when clicked it should download current image. 
It is working fine in android and desktop browser, using small server-side php script.
But in iphone it simply open's image in the new tab. Yeah, I know, you can easily download image simply by long-tapping, but well. I'm not the one who want this)

Script:

```
<?php

$file = $_GET['f'];
$file = "images/com_product/product/large/".$file;
download_file($file);

function download_file( $fullPath ){

  // Must be fresh start
  if( headers_sent() )
    die('Headers Sent');

  // Required for some browsers
  if(ini_get('zlib.output_compression'))
    ini_set('zlib.output_compression', 'Off');

  // File Exists?
  if( file_exists($fullPath) ){

    // Parse Info / Get Extension
    $fsize = filesize($fullPath);
    $path_parts = pathinfo($fullPath);
    $ext = strtolower($path_parts["extension"]);

    // Determine Content Type
    switch ($ext) {
      case "gif": $ctype="image/gif"; break;
      case "png": $ctype="image/png"; break;
      case "jpeg":
      case "jpg": $ctype="image/jpg"; break;
    }

    header("Pragma: public"); // required
    header("Expires: 0");
    header("Cache-Control: must-revalidate, post-check=0, pre-check=0");
    header("Cache-Control: private",false); // required for certain browsers
    header("Content-Type: $ctype");
    header("Content-Disposition: attachment; filename=\"".basename($fullPath)."\";" );
    header("Content-Transfer-Encoding: binary");
    header("Content-Length: ".$fsize);
    ob_clean();
    flush();
    readfile( $fullPath );

  } else
    die('File Not Found');

}
?>
```

Comment: My first guess, iOS does not support this. Since it does not have a public file system, safari will just display known file type. Unknown file types will just do nothing.

Answer (score 1):

I know this is little late but put this script right before jQuery Mobile it works for me:

```
 $(document).bind("mobileinit", function(){
          $.mobile.ajaxEnabled = false;
   });
```